# Given $\langle z, w\rangle$, find $\langle w, z\rangle$ method.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, inner-products

I'm doing this math problem where we're given the value of $\langle z, w\rangle$ and $\lVert z\rVert$ and we're asked to find
$\langle w, z\rangle$ .

$\langle z, w\rangle = 1-7j$
and $\lVert z\rVert = 5$ (these aren't the actual numbers but they're in this format).

I know that $\langle w, z\rangle$ is $\langle z, w\rangle$ with the conjugate symbol over the entire symbol, but I'm not sure how to approach the question after that. There are no examples in my textbook and no further explanations for this problem.

I'm not asking people to solve the problem for me, but perhaps give me some hints on what to do next.

Thanks.

Comment: The dot product is the standard inner product ?

Comment: @Bayesianguy: If you are MathJaxing anyway, why not use the proper delimiters instead of the inequality signs?

Comment: @Bayesian guy I was told that the complex inner product (which is what I have here) is the conjugate z components times the corresponding w components?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I forgot to change it. Sorry.

Comment: @leah what is the actual problem?

Comment: @leah Regarding your comment, that is what is referred to as the "standard inner product".

Comment: @leah Do you understand what the "conjugate symbol" means? For instance, can you simplify $\overline{1 - 7j}$?

Comment: @leah You don't actually need the $||z||$ here, you only need $\langle w, z \rangle = \overline{\langle z, w \rangle}$.